# can't get wordpress working thru sql ports

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to setup wordpress port. How can I find the port not in use and how to activate them? I can't seem to get answers on closed ports and how to open them.

Comment: Are you sure there is no help about this in the Manual, on SO or the wider net?

Comment: Have you asked on the [WordPress site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)?